# Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova - How to select Cordova Version?

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

Is there a way to select what Cordova version to use when using Visual Studio 2013? Or is it fixed at whatever VS allows. I noticed Cordova 4.0 was recently released an would like to use it.

Comment: Note that Cordova 4 is not what was released, it is Cordova-CLI 4 that was released. The current version of cordova is 3.6.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can manually update the Cordova version. Here are the steps to do this [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn757054.aspx)

Comment: using the method described in the Link above I was able to install Cordova version 4.1.2 which fixed the iOS navigator.platform bug.